# Does anyone recognize this recurrence relation?

Tags: combinatorics

$C_{n,k}=C_{n-1,k}+C_{n,k-1}$ with $C_{0,k}=C_{n,0}=1$? There must be some closed-form, I hope. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a variation of the binomial coefficients in the form of an infinite 2D array. That is, $C_{n,k}=(n+k)!/(n!k!)$. The usual version is in the form of an infinite triangular table known as Pascal's triangle.

Comment: Very well detected (+1)!

Comment: Indeed! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

These are the binomial coefficients $$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!\cdot (n-k)!}$$  but as shown in the answer below, we do not simply have $C(n,k)=\binom{n}{k}$, but $$C(n,k)=\binom{n+k}{k}$$

Comment: Are you sure? I thought $C_{n,k}=C_{n-1,k-1}+C_{n-1,k}$ stood for binomials.

Comment: Thank you, Peter! I now see it all! :)

Comment: @user75619 To be honest, I did not recognize that the recurrence relation was false.for $\binom{n}{k}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $L_{n,k}$ is the number of lattice paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n,k)$ using $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ steps. We claim $C_{n,k}=L_{n,k}$.

Indeed there is only one way to get to $(0,k)$ and $(n,0)$ (move all the way up and move all the way to right respectively). Hence $L_{n,0}=L_{0,k}=1$.

Now classify the paths based on whether the first step is a $(1,0)$ or $(0,1)$ step. If the first step is $(0,1)$ there are $L_{n,k-1}$ paths and if the first step is $(1,0)$ there are $L_{n-1,k}$ paths. Hence
$$
L_{n,k}=L_{n-1,k}+L_{n,k-1};\quad L_{n,0}=L_{0,k}=1.
$$
Hence $L_{n,k}=C_{n,k}$.

But the the number of lattice paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n,k)$ is in bijection with words of length $n+k$ over the alphabet $\{U, R\}$ with $k$ letters which are $R$ and $n$ letters which are $U$. Here $U$ corresponds to a $(0,1)$ step and $R$ corresponds to a $(1,0)$ step. Hence
$$
C_{n,k}=\binom{n+k}{k}.
$$